# How to add the IEnumerable collection to ICollection list?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable, icollection

I add the method for adding Ienumerable collection to Icollection.

```
public static ICollection<T> AddTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,ICollection<T> collection) {
    foreach (T item in list) {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

But at first time initialized collection variable as null.Then i am getting "Object reference not found error"please tell me how to add Ienumerable list data to Icollection properly?

EDIT:

```
 ICollection<UserInApplication> userInAppRole=null;
                IEnumerable<UserInApplication> result=null;
   result = _userService.UserInApplicationRoles(iAppRoleId,  collection["displayName"]).AsEnumerable();
     userInAppRole = Extensions.AddTo<UserInApplicationRole>(result,userInAppRole);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code (except a little parameter validation). Show us how you're calling it.

Comment: Better use `AddRange` (similar to List<>) and swap parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your collection. And extension methods can be called in a better way.

```
ICollection<UserInApplication> userInAppRole=new Collection<UserInApplication>(); //Initialize this
IEnumerable<UserInApplication> result=null;
result = _userService.UserInApplicationRoles(iAppRoleId,collection["displayName"])
                     .AsEnumerable();
 userInAppRole = result.AddTo(userInAppRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
ICollection<UserInApplication> userInAppRole=null;
IEnumerable<UserInApplication> result=null;
result = _userService.UserInApplicationRoles(iAppRoleId,  collection["displayName"]).AsEnumerable();
userInAppRole = Extensions.AddTo<UserInApplicationRole>(result,userInAppRole)
```

You're never instantiating a collection in the `userInAppRole` variable; it's null. When you try to add `result` into a null, you get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ICollection<T> AddTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,ICollection<T> collection) {
  if ((null != list) || (null != collection)) {    
    foreach (T item in list) {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
  }
    return collection;
}
```